# Is there a way of making Catagories searchable

Tags: html

I have a plugin with a search function. The function itself is fine except it doesn't search catagories.

Is there a simple way to make it search catagories? The Catagories are all there, the only problem is that when you search the files, it doesn't search catagories for your key-word.

So if you type in 'book', for example, it will only look for ads with the word book in, not ads listed under catagory 'books'

Comment: It is confusing what you are asking as this is tagged as "HTML".

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. Yes, is it possible to do with html?